# GL/glew.h: no include path set

Tags: c++17, glew, vcpkg

I am trying to build a glfw and glew c++ code but while building I am getting the following error:

```
fatal error C1034: GL/glew.h: no include path set
```

any help is appreciated.

**OS**: Windows 10

**compiler**: MSVC++ 17.0.3

**package-installer**: vcpkg

**IDE**: Visual Studio Code

**Build**: Cmake

*CmakeLists.txt :*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(my_project VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE C:/Users/pc/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

add_executable(
  my_project
  main.cpp
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  c:/Users/pc/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include/
)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(
  c:/Users/pc/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib/
)

find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(freetype CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(glm CONFIG REQUIRED)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_project
  glfw glm::glm GLEW::GLEW freetype fmt::fmt
)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Comment: Have you used https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGLEW.html ?
i.e. find_package(GLEW) and linked your target against GLEW::GLEW ?

Comment: @AlexanderNeumann yh. see the added CmakeLists.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` after `project(my_project VERSION 0.1.0)` does not work since `project(my_project VERSION 0.1.0)` loads the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`. So move it before `project()`

Also remove

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  c:/Users/pc/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include/
)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(
  c:/Users/pc/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib/
)
```

since linking against the above targets should be more than enough! (also always use `target_*` functions instead.)

Furthermore increase

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
```

to something reasonable. You probably don't plan on supporting ancient versions of cmake. If you don't need to support ancient linux distros you can just move to at least 3.17. If you only plan to support windows you can directly move to 3.22 or use whatever vs uses. vcpkg is currently at 3.21.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked like a charm for me. The cmake version was put there by default configuration so i had missed it.